# distinguishing two biased coins

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, probability-theory, probabilistic-algorithms

I had a simple probability question: suppose we have two coins, coin 1 is heads with probability $= 10\epsilon$ and coin 2 is heads with probability $=\epsilon/10$. Given an unknown coin, how many times do I need to flip the coin to decide which coin I have been given? I feel the right answer is $\Theta(1/\epsilon^2)$, but I don't see how to prove it.

Comment: I believe Therem (6) here (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.144.2360&rep=rep1&type=pdf) might have an aswer to this question

Comment: If you have 10/eps coin flips you expect either 100 heads or 1 heads. That should be plenty to distinguish the coins. Of course only with high probability, not 100%.

Comment: Complementing gnasher729’s algorithm (which can be analyzed rigorously using concentration of measure), there is a simple lower bound of $\Omega(1/\epsilon)$: when only $1/N\epsilon$ coins are tossed, in both cases it is highly likely that there will be no heads, and so the variation distance between the two distributions will be very small.

Comment: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/22328/5038